# mysql scheduled procedure create columns

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I want to scheduled procedure and create columns very year via procedure script.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `yeniyil`()
BEGIN
-- declare years text(10);
-- SET years = "t"+year;
declare years INT;
set years = concat(years);
SET years = concat((year(current_DATE)));

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns where COLUMN_NAME=years and TABLE_NAME='kullanicilar' and TABLE_SCHEMA ='agcevrepm') THEN
SELECT years;
alter table kullanicilar add **years**  TEXT(10);
END IF;

END
```

I write script as above. However, this script try create "years" columns but I want to create  call "2013" or "2014"

how can i solve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you adding columns to a table? Just set up the database without this need. Read about third normal form

Comment: If you still want to do this, look up _dynamic SQL_

Comment: How are you going to update all your queries to use the new column every year?